# Task.Factory.StartNew() or Task.Run() correct usage?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am new to multithreading and I’m hard time of making sense of all the ways to do it with tasks. I am trying to implement it in a big program but no one wants to look at all thousands of lines of processing code for no reason so i have write a simple test program that uses Sleep() instead of doing real work and made it real simple.

Question is as the bottom.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BlockingCollection<int> col = new BlockingCollection<int>();
            for(int z = 0; z<=50; z++)
            {
                col.Add(z);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hi from main! ThreadID: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hi from PARENT! ThreadID: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                foreach (int num in col.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(num*100);
                            if (num == 50)
                            {
                                col.CompleteAdding(); //kick out of the foreach loop
                                Thread.Sleep(25000);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("Hi from a Child! ThreadID: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                        }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Parent done making children. ThreadID: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            var final = parent.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DONE!");
            },TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion
                );

            Console.WriteLine("Calling Wait on final. ThreadID: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            final.Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The code adds 51 elements to a blocking collection and then starts up a task called Parent. Parent consumes items from the blocking collection until it is marked with `CompleteAdding()` is called on it.

The parent task is long running as i don't want it pulling threads from the threadpool. It should then spawn attached child tasks that will sleep for some time  and if the element is '50' it calls `CompleteAdding()`.

Then there is a continuation called `final` that only runs if the parent ran to completion. And the parent can only be complete if the blocking collection is done being added too and all the child task are also complete.

I then call `final.Wait()` from main (in my real program the the `final.Wait()` will likely be in the `OnFormClosing()` method.)

The whole point of doing all this is to be able to ensure before the program closes all currently running work is finished and all queued work is also finished.

This is where the question is. I have seen in many places that I should use `Task.Run()` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew()` so I tried changing them out and I start getting errors saying `Error CS1643  Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func<Task>'` why do i need a return value if I don't want a return. Also Is this proper use of `Task.Factory.StartNew()` or am I doing something risky/dangerous?

*note* Not sure if it matters but in the program I am going to use this setup in the sleeps with be stuff like matching data and sending it out to an oracle db. Also we can't go higher than .NET 4.6

Comment: You don't need a `BlockingCollection` to start 50 tasks, just use a normal for loop. Oh, and **capture the loop variable**. By the time a task runs `num` could well be 50 for all your tasks.

Comment: It seems to me, you're trying to bypass what the TAP system was designed to do, and instead trying to re-create it yourself using a "long running thread" because you don't want to pull a thread from the thread pool.  Why?  This is exactly what the TAP system does, it schedules a whole bunch of tasks to be completed and then ensures they all get completed.

Comment: I am aware of that. The goal isnt to start 50 tasks, but to ensure that the all the 'work', in this case a int, is pulled from the queue until we are sure no more will be added, and that all work is done finished before the program exits. but where this is all being applied in the end it is a workitem object that has instructions and data the instructions should act on and the work items are created as new data becomes available. could be 50 items in an hour or could be 50000 items over 20 min. No way of knowing.

Comment: @CodingGorilla Are we assured they completed. if i start a task that waits for 10 min and  creates a text file, and right after the task is started the I close the program is the text file created? Whole point is that the program can't exit until all work is done.

Comment: @user5999614 No, if you end the process then clearly the task will not complete, but that is true of the code you have here.  You cannot make code run if it's owning process ends.  If your problem is keeping the `main` from exiting before the work is complete, there are _tons_ of other ways to handle that problem, recreating the TAP and thread queues (IMO) is not the way to deal with it.

Comment: I read somewhere once to always use task.factory.startnew over task.run. Im guessing its because it is smarter in how it assigns tasks to the threadpool. I would agree with Scott and just use task.factory.startnew if it works. It would help if  you would describe the scenario in which you think tas.run is more appropriate.

Comment: @CodingGorrila Sorry I thought i made it clear. In the end this is going in a winform application so i can put the wait in the onformclosing. That will stop the owning process from ending until all tasks are done when i click the applications close button or if a fatal crash happens.

Comment: @codemonkeyliketab I don't know if there is a scenario where it is better, I just keep seeing stuff saying not to use `task.factory.startnew` unless you know what you are doing because its dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify the `Task.Run` version of your code:

```
Task.Run(() => { }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

This code is wrong: [there is no overload of `Task.Run()` accepting `TaskCreationOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run). But the error message reported by the C# compiler ("Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type '`Func<Task>`'") is also wrong. I think this is a bug in the C# compiler, so [I reported it](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10672).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's documentation describes `Task.Run`as the 'simpler way' to run a task asynchronously. It and `Task.Factory.StartNew` both return a `Task` and the syntax is the same. I'd be interested in seeing the code that's giving you a compile error. But if your code is working with `Task.Factory.StartNew` I don't see a compelling reason to change it.

```
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.Write("Doing");
            Console.Write("Something");
        });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.Write("Doing");
            Console.Write("Something");
        });
```

Comment: you can copy paste my code as is and just change the `Task.Factory.StartNew` to `Task.Run` and that should reproduce the error.